# Как подсчитать количество значений в объекте с определенным значением?

Tags: javascript

Как подсчиать количество значений где `"marked": "1"` ?

Как нибудь с минималистичным кодом, как то через  filter или reduce или как то еще, просто число узнать количество записей

```js
let obj = {
  "models": [
    {
      "id": "1075",
      "last": "1",
      "marked": "0"
    },
    {
      "id": "1073",
      "last": "0",
      "marked": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "1066",
      "last": "0",
      "marked": "1"
    }
  ]
};
console.log(obj['models'].length);
```

Comment: А у вас в чём трудность применения этих методов?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, не могу понять как это реализовать

Comment: ой да ладно. док почитать внимательно надо и всё

Comment: Читал, там только пишут про сравнение, но а как колличество узнать неизвестно

Comment: фильтруешь все где marked 1, потом смотришь length (это если с filter)

Comment: с reduce как раз именно количество и можно посчитать... задав начальное значение 0 и на каждой итерации acc+1 делать если в элементе есть marked 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let object = obj.models.filter(model => model.marked == "1")
```

**model** - элементы массива models. Он перебирает каждый и если условие выполняется, то его сохраняет. После того, как все элементы профильтруются, полученный новый массив возвращается

а количество просто массива получившегося посчитай через **object.length**

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, добавил length в конце `console.log( obj.models.filter(model => model.marked == "1").length );`

Comment: если про минимализм, то `obj.models.reduce((acc,v) => +acc+v.marked,0)` короче будет